# Unusual drainage problem

Tags: drainage

I cut a mature apple tree on my lawn and pulled out the stump. And it seems that I got a minor drainage problem because of that in a few years: I see a much stronger flow at the place where the water flows down hill on the side of landscaped evergreen ground cover.

The apple tree in question was about 30' and on the level from the place where I see the increased flow. Is it possible that the tree provided some minimal drainage that reduced the flow through evergreens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apple tree will have been using some of the water for itself, so removing it would mean there is now more free water, which might have increased the flow you notice. Otherwise, perhaps you have had an increase in rainfall generally.